Hough transformation: get line function from Hough parameters (rho, theta)
I have two an input image (256px x 256px) with a line and Hough space image (256px x 256px) with a mark where the corresponding Hough parameters are:

Coordinates of the dot on the right hand image are (x=64, y=128).
These coordinates corrspond to the values $\rho$ for y, and $\theta$ for x in the Hough space (see Wikipedia article for more info).
I want to accomplish using the values $\rho$, and $\theta$ to calculate a function which plots a line similar to the white line from the input image.
As I understand it, $\rho$ has been calculated with
$\rho = x\cdot cos(\theta) + y\cdot sin(\theta) \quad \quad \quad(1)$
$(1)$ can be transformed into:
$y= \frac{-cos(\theta)}{sin(\theta)} \cdot x + \frac{\rho}{sin(\theta)} \quad \quad \quad(2)$
However, this is not resulting in what I expected:  see plot of function in wolframalpha with $\theta = 64°$, and $\rho = 128$ (Wolframalpha assumes degrees, here).
I think I must adjust $\rho$ and $theta$ somehow, when calculating the function.
But how?
Update:
Like discussed in the comments, I have to adjust $\theta$ by a factor $\frac{180}{squareWidth}$, because the $\theta$ in Hough space goes from $0°$ to $180°$. Besides that, I have to adjust the $\rho$ with a factor of $\sqrt{2}$. This is because the maximal distance from the center can be $squareWidth \cdot \sqrt{2}$.
$\rho' = \rho \cdot \sqrt{2} \\ \theta' = \frac{\theta \cdot 180}{squareWidth}$
This works for calculating a function to plot a line similar to the original line, in the example above.
But if I have an example, like the one on the Wikipedia page (Example 2), this here:

For reference: $\rho = 112$, and $\theta = 128$, because the second red dot in the middle of the right image is (x=128; y=112). This means that $\rho' = 112 \cdot \sqrt{2}$, and $\theta' = 90$.
Then I get the following two graphs:
Desmos link
You can just reflect the graphs by the x-axis to flip it vertically.
See where the lines cross the x- and y-axis (these are the image boundaries TOP and LEFT) to understand what it produces.
You can see, that it misplaces the horizontal line.
Another example:
Look at this pair:

Second red dot is (x=193; y=128), makes for $\theta' = 135$, and $\rho' = 128 \cdot \sqrt{2}$. Note that $\rho$, $\rho'$ are the same for the two dots in this example.
Plot: Desmos Link Example 3
Again, flip it vertically in your mind.
In all examples, the calculated functions (and their graphs) have the correct inclinations, but they are somehow misplaced.
It really looks like a small problem here. I just want to have formula for adjusting $\rho$, and $\theta$ correctly.

Could it be that the origin in your image is in the top-left corner? It is common in computer graphics to have the $y$-axis increase downwards instead of up. You can try inverting the wolfram alpha plot vertically and see if that’s what you expect

I might be sceptical about the original values as well. Shouldn’t the angle be 45 degrees? (or some odd multple)

Perhaps the critical missing information here is: How did you get/generate the image and values?

@Milten: yes, you're right. i corrected $\theta$ with the factor $180/256$, i.o. to interpret as $\in [-\pi; \pi]$. it's then 45°.

@Milten: you're also right about the image calculation direction (top-down, not down-up), so this is the currently plot y = cos(45)/sin(45)} * x + -128/sin(45)

*correction: $\theta \in [\frac{-\pi}{2};\frac{\pi}{2}]$

Oh, I think I see now. Then you need a scale factor for $\rho$ as well, which should be $\sqrt2$ as far as I can tell from your values. Basically you think about the original line image where the angle is 45 deg and the distance is $128\sqrt2$

Can you please provide how the images are generated? It would make it much easier to help
